# Unable to mount via sshfs (fuse: permission denied)

Tags: unix, ubuntu, fuse

So, I installed sshfs on my Ubuntu 10.04 and tried to mount a remote server directory.

Unfortunately, I got the error many users got:

```
fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied
```

So, I went on Google and tried pretty much everything - chmod /dev/fuse with all the flags I could find, add my user (root) to fuse group, rebooting, etc. Nothing helped.

My current state of /dev/fuse

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root fuse 10, 229 Aug 28 20:01 /dev/fuse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, after researching some more, it turned out that I did not set the appropriate permissions after all... It works like a charm now :)